# opening a file from a path written in a text file?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim objectreader As New System.IO.StreamReader(TextBox1.Text)
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("TextBox2.Text = objectreader.ReadToEnd()")
        objectreader.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

I am trying to read from a text file where i have written a path to a file. I have been able to open a file using `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()` and I have been able to read from a text file using `StreamReader`  but I could not relate to it. How do I take the text from the text file and put it in the `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("here")` to open the file. I am using vb.net visual studio 2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the quotes.  You aren't providing a string literal, you're providing the result of a method call:

```
TextBox2.Text = objectreader.ReadToEnd()
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(TextBox2.Text)
```